# Does Access VBA use different credentials than logged in user to access network folder?

Tags: excel, ms-access, networking, vba

I'm trying to link to an Excel spreadsheet from a Microsoft Access 2016 database. I was given permission to the folder that contains the Excel spreadsheet and am able to create/open/edit files there now. The problem with linking this spreadsheet is the worksheet name will change without notice (it's exported from another program).

I can create a linked table in the Access GUI to the Excel spreadsheet and queries run fine, but when the worksheet name changes the link is broken. I thought I can just delete and re-link the spreadsheet, or delete/re-import each time the Access database is opened using the DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet method but I get error 3051: File is locked or you don't have permission (paraphrased).

I know the code works because I moved the spreadsheet to a different shared folder of mine and it links perfectly. I put a test spreadsheet in the folder I need to access and it gives me the same error.

So it works everywhere except the folder I need it to work in. Everything seems to me to be pointing to a permissions problem but my Sys Admin says that's not the issue.

Why does it work from the GUI but not the VBA? I know for certain the file isn't open by anyone/anything. Does the VBA use different credentials than the logged in user?

It fails on this line:
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "tblWeeklySeniorityReport", StrXls, True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

We have multiple Access DBs running from Windows Scheduled Tasks. The problem with this task is that it was set to "Run with Highest Privileges". It must run this way with some sort of admin user which wasn't given permissions to the folder it needs to access. I unchecked this box and it runs with the logged in user creds, which does have access to the folder.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

that command is importing, not linking. when you have a file on a network share, assume it can be open my multiple people. folder permissions can also come into play. I would copy the file locally, and then import it. use filecopy, then try the import

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The file won't (shouldn't) be open when the code runs as it runs in the middle of the night. That line of code in OP imports, but I've also tried acLink and get same error. I tried the FileCopy method and I get Run-time error 75: Path/File access error.

Comment: when you say middle of the night, where does it run? i assume it is a scheduled job on some machine? if so, you need to give the service account that runs this job the proper privileges to access that folder on the network. so this is undoubtedly a permissions issue, not a code issue